# Spiderweb chart with different axis ranges (parallel-coordinates)

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have angular service which provides highcharts config for highcharts-ng. I prepare data for this service in controller and than call service with data as parameter. All work. But if my range is for example something like this [15,130,0.2] my spiderweb chart is little bit squeezed. So I would like to do different axis scales and I have found solution by using `parallel-coordinates.js`.

And I have problem to make it works. First picture is what I have and second is what I would like to achieve.

What I have : https://jsfiddle.net/DuFuS/en51rbxc/

What I want: http://jsfiddle.net/DuFuS/tbzfhou5/

[image: What I have] 
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all (and the most important thing), you're using very old version of `highcharts-ng` package, and that's why `parallel-coordinates.js` module isn't working properly.

This module create additional axes basing on the amount of data passed to the chart constructor, but in this version of package, `data` is unfortunately an empty object on chart init, so the `parallel-coordinates.js` module doesn't add any additional axis at all.

Next things which causes the problems are typos in configuration here:

```
chart: {
  parallerlCoordinates: true,
  parallerAxes: {
...
```

Should be `parallelCoordinates` and `parallelAxes`.

In order to make your chart works, please update the version of `highcharts-ng` package to 1.2.1, then rebuild your configuration object (because the structure had changed with new version), like below:

```
return {
      chart: {
        parallelCoordinates: true,
        parallelAxes: {
          gridLineWidth: 0,
          lineWidth: 2,
          showFirstLabel: false,
          showLastLabel: true
        },
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: data.categories,
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0
      },
      yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
      },
      series: data.series
    };
```

After all changes, chart will look as you expected.

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/rza5uk67/

**Package docs:** https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: Is it possible to show legend for this kind of chart because it doesn't show even if I set enabled to true.

Comment: Of course. Just set the `legend: { enabled: true }`. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/31ox70r6/